# /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches values

Tags: linux, performance, cache, ram

I want to know what values are possible for `drop_caches`, and what the meaning of that values are.

For example:

```
echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

What does number `3` mean?
Are the numbers, `1`, `2` or other numbers true? if yes what are the meaning of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting directly from the documentation at 
https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sysctl/vm.txt, which is trivial to find with a simple google search for 'linux drop_caches':

> drop_caches
>
> Writing to this will cause the kernel to drop clean caches, as well as
>   reclaimable slab objects like dentries and inodes.  Once dropped, their
>   memory becomes free.
>
> To free pagecache:
>
> echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
>
> To free reclaimable slab objects (includes dentries and inodes):
>
> echo 2 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
>
> To free slab objects and pagecache:
>
> echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
>
> This is a non-destructive operation and will not free any dirty objects.
>   To increase the number of objects freed by this operation, the user may run
>   `sync' prior to writing to /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches.  This will minimize the
>   number of dirty objects on the system and create more candidates to be
>   dropped.
>
> This file is not a means to control the growth of the various kernel caches
>   (inodes, dentries, pagecache, etc...)  These objects are automatically
>   reclaimed by the kernel when memory is needed elsewhere on the system.
>
> Use of this file can cause performance problems.  Since it discards cached
>   objects, it may cost a significant amount of I/O and CPU to recreate the
>   dropped objects, especially if they were under heavy use.  Because of this,
>   use outside of a testing or debugging environment is not recommended.
>
> You may see informational messages in your kernel log when this file is
>   used:
>
> cat (1234): drop_caches: 3
>
> These are informational only.  They do not mean that anything is wrong
>   with your system.  To disable them, echo 4 (bit 3) into drop_caches.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Now for prevent ram to be full simultaneously, is it a good solution? The ram is being full after two days and cuase errors....

Comment: No, because the kernel should be automatically evicting data from the caches by itself when space is needed.  If you're having issues with out-of-memory conditions, you've got a memory leak somewhere, and dropping caches is not going to solve that.